# Show recent blog image on home page bigcommerce?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bigcommerce

how can I call blog Summary thumbnail image or content image on the home page? I want to show latest blogs on homepage with date and thumbnail is there any way to achieve this:--

There is two part:

one with stencil big commerce Framework 
2nd one with classic next or normal theme with bigcommerce

Need the help any of way with stencil framework or normal theme. below both of themes code please review and suggest me.

Normal themes:--need to modify recent blog snippet.

```
<div class="RecentNews" id="HomeRecentBlogs" style="display:%%GLOBAL_HideHomeRecentBlogsPanel%%">
  <div class="inner">
  <h4>%%LNG_RecentNews%%</h4>
  <ul>
  %%GLOBAL_Thumbnail%%
  %%SNIPPET_BlogRecentPostsContentItem.html%%
  </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
```

stencil framework:--I have called this code on home.html

```
 {{#if post.thumbnail}}
  <figure class="blog-thumbnail">
  <a href="{{post.url}}">
  <img src="{{getImage post.thumbnail 'blog_size'}}" alt="{{post.thumbnail.alt}}" title="{{post.thumbnail.alt}}">
  </a>
  </figure>
  {{/if}}
```

if i can acchive javascript then how I can do this please suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In stencil, you need to remove `post.` since the global `blog.recent_posts` structure if different than `blog.posts` and for some reason.

```
{{#each blog.recent_posts}}
    {{#if thumbnail}}
        <figure class="blog-thumbnail">
            <a href="{{url}}">
                <img src="{{getImage thumbnail 'blog_size'}}" alt="{{thumbnail.alt}}" title="{{thumbnail.alt}}">
            </a>
        </figure>
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

For blueprint themes, you should be able to add the variable `%%Panel.HomeRecentBlogs%%` anywhere on the home page to load the panel.

Comment: wow, you save me a lot thanks, man ! thats I exactly need. Thank you so much.

Comment: please can you help me to sort out it in normal themes ?

Comment: I updated the answer to include blueprint "normal" themes

Comment: but with the help of %%Panel.HomeRecentBlogs%% it is showing the only name and description not image the main issue with image of blog not showing front home page